# Parts of my model wont move after Auto Weight Painting

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

OK i'm new to blender and have been working on this model. After i was done Rigging and auto weighting i came across this problem.

[image]

I tried to manually Weight Paint it but nothing happens, i would be thankful for some help

Comment: In Weight Paint mode you must choose the Add Option for your brush. Other solution: Select your foot in edit mode, then go to the Properties > Object Data > Vertex Groups, and in the down arrow (on the right) click "Remove from All Groups", then choose the Vertex Group corresponding to the feet name (for example foot.L) and click Assign

Comment: Could you upload your blend files here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can try to help you?

Comment: I try to send the file all it said was "The provided url is not valid, please copy and paste the entire url, including the "https://" header."